# После запуска docker не заходит в приложение

Tags: python, docker, flask

Есть веб сервис на python(flask). При запуске контейнера не могу зайти по указанному адресу, хотя локально все работает.

```
FROM centos:centos7
LABEL maintainer=".....ru"
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python36; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python36-pip; yum clean all;
RUN /bin/pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN /bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "local_app.py", "-c", "config.json"]
```

собирается без ошибок,
запускаю (специально не демоном, что бы был виден лог) :
docker run

```
{'__module__': 'app.config', 'TESTING': True, 'DEBUG': True, 'SQLALCHEMY_ECHO': False, '__doc__': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'postgresql:....'}
Map([<Rule '/reports/queue_statuses' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> reports_api.queue_statuses>,
 <Rule '/reports/current_state' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, POST) -> reports_api.create_report>,
 <Rule '/reports' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> reports_api.get_file_list>,
 <Rule '/get_report/<filename>' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> reports_api.get_report>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> static>])
 * Serving Flask app "sev-reports" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
2020-02-27 12:47:27,443 [INFO] -  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-02-27 12:47:27,444 [INFO] -  * Restarting with stat
2020-02-27 12:47:28,434 [WARNING] -  * Debugger is active!
2020-02-27 12:47:28,435 [INFO] -  * Debugger PIN: 790-794-760
```

По указанному адресу доступа к приложению нет. Порты пробрасывал

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - это чисто локальный адрес, на него нельзя зайти удаленно. У докер-контейнера настроено сетевое подключение?

Comment: так я докер и запускаю локально и на той же машине и пытаюсь подключиться.

Comment: к 127.0.0.1 контейнера можно подключиться только исключительно изнутри докер-контейнера. Нужно что бы сервис внутри докера запускался на 0.0.0.0 (прослушивал на всех адресах) вместо 127.0.0.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615551/how-to-publish-flask-port-from-container-to-host

вот тут, скорее всего, похожая проблема и решение.

Comment: @Morewind это не так, еслти пробросить порты. 
Покажите команду запуска и на какой операционке вы это запускаете?

Comment: docker run <app:v> 
так же прописывал порт с -p
-d не ставлю что бы смотреть лог